# Programmatic Custom UIButton Does Not Appear After Timer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, subviews

I have been trying to write a program in which a button appears after a timer fires. The timer is working properly, as is the firing event (I have tested this with different events). However, the button I am making appear is not showing up. Also, I would like the button background image to change when the button is pressed and held. I have tried making the button just have a background color instead of an image, but that does not work either. The code is located in the Timer selector within the view controller Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
- (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer *)timer
{
Button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
Button.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2);
[Button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonUnheldBGImage"]
                                      forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[Button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonHeldBGImage"]
                                      forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[Button setTitle:@"Press and Hold" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[Button addTarget:self action:@selector(aSelector:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:Button];
}
```

The timer class that calls this is:

```
- (void)timer
{

globalTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5
                                      target:self
                                    selector:@selector(timerFireMethod:)
                                    userInfo:Nil
                                     repeats:NO];

}
```

globalTimer is a global NSTimer

Comment: provide code for aSelector method..

Comment: are you running this program on an iPhone or an iPad ?

Comment: Salman, The "aSelector" method is not implemented yet. It is declared, but it does not do anything. I don't think it should throw off the appearance of the button though.
Emilie, I am running this on an iPhone. Also, if it helps, the button images are located in the same folder as the view controller class.

Comment: edit the post and provide the code where you are initializing NSTimer.

Comment: Do you use a scrollview ? Because your button seems to be out of the screen if you're testing on 3.5" display

Comment: Oh ok, I think the scroll view might be the issue. Do you know of an adjustable programmatic way to position the button frame in the center of the view?

Comment: `Button.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2,self.frame.size.height/2);`

Comment: Thanks! But the button still will not appear... I removed the CGRectMake line to allow for the new position

Comment: You have to keep the frame also.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I added the frame back in and now it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the center of the button but you also need the frame of it, i believe that the button is showing now but his frame is (0,0).

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a size to your button as well. If you want it at the center of your super view just do :

```
CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2-100,self.view.frame.size.height/2-100, 200,200);
Button.frame = buttonFrame;
```

The center property is essentialy used for UI Element that already have a size.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your first 2 lines,

```
UIButton * Button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
Button.frame = CGRectMake(20, 200, 200, 200);
```